# How to show output in a separate terminal on VScode similar to Atom Editor for C/C++

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

So I prefer VScode due to the added features and speed,but I have one problem.I prefer my output in a separate terminal like **cmd**.In atom the **gpp compiler** package does that for me.But in VScode,output is displayed in a in-built terminal below your code.I usually dont prefer that as it becomes difficult for me to see the output properly since I have a small screen.

So how can I do that in **VSCode**?